# input names for dict from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Rather than manually inputting names for dict using the info from a dataframe as such:

```
d = {}
d['d0']='2022-06-01'
d['d1']='2022-06-05'
d['d2']='2022-06-08'
d['d3']='2022-06-12'
d['d4']='2022-06-22'
d['d5']='2022-06-25'
d['d6']='2022-06-28'
```

Is it possible to use the output of the dataframe and convert them to dict name instead of manual input?

sample df:

```
╔════════════╗
║    date    ║
╠════════════╣
║ 2022-06-01 ║
║ 2022-06-05 ║
║ 2022-06-08 ║
║ 2022-06-12 ║
║ 2022-06-22 ║
║ 2022-06-25 ║
║ 2022-06-28 ║
╚════════════╝
```

code for sample df:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'date':['2022-06-01','2022-06-05','2022-06-08','2022-06-12','2022-06-22','2022-06-25','2022-06-28']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Yes, you can!](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

Comment: Note that is going to give you a dictionary inside another dictionary, so you may have to do something like `d = df.to_dict()['date']`.

Comment: @Ignatius Reilly, thank you for the reply and link. What do you mean by "a dictionary inside another dictionary"? I'm planning to use the dict for multiple loops, would that create a logic problem?

Comment: If you do dic = `df.to_dict()`, you'll get `{'data' : { 0 : '2022-06-01', 1: '2022-06-05', ....`. So if now you do `d = dic['data']` (or, in a single operation: `d = df.to_dict()['date']`), this is exactly what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Do a little dictionary comprehension on the output of `df.to_dict()` to get it into the format you're looking for:

```py
d = {f'd{i}':v for i, v in df.to_dict()['date'].items()}
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{
   'd0': '2022-06-01',
   'd1': '2022-06-05',
   'd2': '2022-06-08',
   'd3': '2022-06-12',
   'd4': '2022-06-22',
   'd5': '2022-06-25',
   'd6': '2022-06-28'
}
```